# Rebase when base commit hash's have changed completely due to `git rebase -i`

Tags: git

All this work is local.

1. Initially I was on branch "X" and it had 2 commits.
2. I then did `git checkout -b Y`, so this made a 2nd branch based on branch X.
3. I now have a commit on branch Y.
4. I had to go back to branch X and did a `git rebase -i HEAD~2` to change code in the 1st of the 2 commits on branch X. So this changed the commit hash's.
5. I now came back to branch Y and tried `git rebase X`, I have two conflicts, however after I resolve them and then `git add` and then do `git rebase --continue` it's saying `No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?` however this is not true, I definitely did do `git add` of the two conflicting files after resolving.

Comment: Typically, this means you resolved the conflicts in such a way that there are no remaining changes to be committed -- ie. that the result is exactly identical to the immediately prior commit. `git rebase --skip` is appropriate in such cases.

Comment: For assistance that's more applicable to your case, we'd need a more precise reproducer -- ideally, a scripted one.

Comment: Oooo let me try that `git rebase --skip` I think you're right! Because i didnt modify the files in changed in branch X in branch Y. It's just basically replacing 2 commits. Let me try that.

Comment: Surely that you should have used `git rebase --onto` to rebase only the last commit(s) and avoid solving some conflicts or empty commits.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `onto` @Philippe - thank you i will reserach that, if possible can you explain it a little more in how it relates to my case above. I learn best by seeing soemthing fulfill a need case.

Comment: An example: https://medium.com/@gabriellamedas/git-rebase-and-git-rebase-onto-a6a3f83f9cce
In your case `git rebase --onto`, would have allowed you to rebase only the last commit of Y onto the new state of X where a normal rebase is rebasing all the commits between the common ancestor the 2 branches and the HEAD of Y ( so, if commits has been amended, you endup having to fix again already solved conflicts)

Comment: Thanks @Philippe! Ill check out that medium article now.